# Nginx - allow user to hit seperate URIs to reach seperate internal copies of the same React app

Tags: reactjs, nginx, .net-core, rancher

**----- SECOND ATTEMPT ------**

The problem and idea is still the same as below, but this is what I have for NGINX now:

```
    set $QA "http://reactapp-qa:80";
    set $DEV "http://reactapp-dev:80";
    set $PROD "http://reactapp-prod:80";

    location /dev {          

        rewrite ^/dev(.*)$ /$1 break;

        proxy_pass $DEV;

    }

    location /qa {          

        rewrite ^/qa(.*)$ /$1 break;

        proxy_pass $QA;

    }

    #reactapp
    location / {          

        rewrite /(.*) /$1 break;

        proxy_pass $PROD;
    }
```

My / location works great

The other locations load the header and some page elements from the app but do not trigger react axios api calls like the / location does, so they fail.

I feel like I am much closer, just need to figure out what is happening with the axios calls.

**----- ORIGINAL POST ------**

**PROBLEM SUMMARY**

We have a React app in a container and nginx in another container in the host.

The configuration works now but we want to make it work a little differently - we want three seperate copies of the React app in their own containers to be reachable from different addresses - but are having problems understanding what we need to do to make it work.

**BACKGROUND**

The app is using React/Dotnetcore app in a stack in a host in Rancher 1.6.

I am not a React Developer but can talk to the one who wrote the app Monday! We also inherited Nginx and i've been learning to use it by trial by fire.

**CONFIGURATION EXAMPLES**

Here is our NGINX location block for our currently functioning configuration. This all works great as outlined in the Actual and Expected Results section below:

```
set $ReactAppDev_url "http://reactapp-development:80";
set $ReactAppQA_url "http://reactapp-qa:80";
set $ReactAppProd_url "http://reactapp-production:80";

location / {          

    rewrite /(.*) /$1 break;

    proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

    resolver {{DNS_RESOLVER}} valid=30s;
    proxy_pass $ReactAppDev_url;

}
```

I'm sure what i've tried as a start is probably going about things the wrong way but replacing the / location blocks with /production was my first attempt. I don't really think I understand how it all fits together despite reading a handful of articles and nginx official docs about the rewrite module and locations:

```
set $ReactAppDev_url "http://reactapp-development:80";
set $ReactAppQA_url "http://reactapp-qa:80";
set $ReactAppProd_url "http://reactapp-production:80";

location /production {          

    rewrite /production/(.*) /$1 break;

    proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

    resolver {{DNS_RESOLVER}} valid=30s;
    proxy_pass $ReactAppProd_url;
}

location /dev {...same as above but dev in rewrite and proxy_pass $ReactAppDev_url}

location /qa {...same as above but qa in rewrite and proxy_pass $ReactAppQA_url}
```

This resulted in the page not working:

```
[error] 29#29: *5 directory index of "/" is forbidden, client: , server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: ""
1/19/2019 8:01:52 PM - - [20/Jan/2019:03:01:52 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 555 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"
```

**ACTUAL AND EXPECTED RESULTS**

Here is what a user does to interact with the site now - this all functions:

- User hits https://www.servername.com/ and the React app shows a login page.
- User enters login credentials and React app detects identity
- If identity is good React app displays https://www.servername.com/request with request data

I am trying to make it so that the user can access one of three uris and be routed to different internal services depending on which uri is hit:

- User hits https://www.servername.com/development> location block above functions
- User hits https://www.servername.com/qa> location block above functions but proxy_pass directive uses ReactAppQA_url instead
- User hits https://www.servername.com/production> location block above functions but proxy_pass directive uses ReactAppProduction_url instead
- Each url is a copy of the app just at a different internal rancher service; user enters login credentials, app detects identity
- If identity is good app opens www.servername.com/request

I'm not sure if this gets configured in Nginx or if the React app itself would need configuration to enable users to reach /development, /qa, /production.

Would anyone be so kind as to offer any suggestions about how we might be able to configure this?

Comment: this is handled in Nginx using rewrite rules where you take the requested url from the user and rewrite the url to access the react app corresponding to that url. also commonly known as reverse proxy. The rewrites are handled by rules that have regex string detection in them here is the link to nginx rewrite doc https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/ hope that helps. But you will need to test rules to fit your needs

Comment: Thank you for confirming that this was all done in nginx and not app side. I've been having problems trying to figure out the rewrite rules but I will keep cracking at it. Appreciate your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up dropping URI's as a method of determining which of three 'environments' a user would want to reach and just used ports instead.

That made the configuration much simpler and made it so that I could just have three server blocks - one listening on 443(production), one listening on port 8443(qa) and one listening on port 8444 (development), each directing users to a different container containing the same app.

Here is a stripped down version of the final version:

```
worker_processes 2;

events {
   worker_connections  8096;
   multi_accept        on;
   use                 epoll;
}

worker_rlimit_nofile 40000;

http {

    include    /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush         on;
    keepalive_timeout  15;

    server { #Handles port 443 traffic (Production)

        #Setup port and server
        listen 443 ssl;       
        server_name {{SERVER_NAME}};

        #omitted SSL and proxy settings

        set $ReactApp1_url "http://reactapp1:81";
        location / {          
            rewrite /(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            resolver {{DNS_RESOLVER}} valid=30s;          
            add_header X-Environment "production";
            proxy_pass $ReactApp1_url;
        }
    }

    server { #Handles port 8444 traffic (Development)
        #Setup port and server
        listen 8444 ssl;
        server_name {{SERVER_NAME}};

        #omitted SSL and proxy settings

        set $ReactApp2_url "http://reactapp2:80";
        location / {          
            rewrite /(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            resolver {{DNS_RESOLVER}} valid=30s;           
            add_header X-Environment "dev";
            proxy_pass $ReactApp2_url;
        }
    }

    server { #Handles all port 8443 traffic (QA)
        listen 8443 ssl;   
        server_name {{SERVER_NAME}};

        #omitted SSL and proxy settings 

        set $ReactApp3_url "http://reactapp3:80";
        location / {          
            rewrite /(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            resolver {{DNS_RESOLVER}} valid=30s;
            add_header X-Environment "qa";
            proxy_pass $ReactApp3_url;
        }
    }
}
```